# In SAS how to combine multiple levels of a variable in a crosstab

Tags: sas

I have a dataset containing an `ID` variable, and a variable that has four levels. I would like to count the number unique ID values by each distinct combination of values of the second variable that occurs in the dataset.

Have:

```
ID  Var2 
-------- 
1   A 
1   B
1   C

2   A
2   B
2   C
2   D

3   A
3   B

4   A 
4   B
4   C

5   A
5   B
5   C

6   A   
6   B
6   C 
6   D
```

Want:

```
Var2         Unique ID
distinct     freq

A            0
B            0    
C            0
D            0
AB           1
AC           0
AD           0
BC           0
BD           0
CD           0
ABC          3     
ABD          0
ACD          0
BCD          0
ABCD         2
```

OR

```
ID  Var2
    context
-------- 
1   ABC
2   ABCD
3   AB
4   ABC
5   ABC
6   ABCD
```

Each observation is a distinct combination of the two variables. Given the second variable has four levels , there are 2^4-1 combinations possible. I would like to create a table that shows me the frequencies of unique `ID`  per each possible combination of values for `Var2`.

I have thought about making a dummy variable with 15 levels according to `Var2`and `ID` and running a proc freq on those 15 levels. I also thought about creating a variable with the concatenated values of `Var2` by `ID`.

I'd like to either create a table like the one above, or a new variable that indicates the `Var2` context for each distinct `ID`.

Comment: Do you have duplicate rows in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your rows are sorted by the two variables (and unique) then you can get what you want with two PROC calls.  If not then add a PROC SORT step with NODUPKEY option.

```
proc transpose data=have out=step1;
  by id ;
  var var2;
run;

proc summary data=step1 nway missing;
  class col: ;
  output out=want ;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    _TYPE_    _FREQ_

 1      A       B                        15         1
 2      A       B       C                15         3
 3      A       B       C       D        15         2
```

Comment: I applied this approach in my working example. Is there a way to extract or flag all observations that fall into each of the three groups according to the results? Basically flagging each observations, or any observation containing the associated ID as 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: You could generate a unique group number per row of the `WANT` and  then join that with the `STEP1` based on the values of the COLxxx variables to get a mapping from your original ID variable to your new group number variable.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is already sorted then you can do dow loop as shown below.

```
data want(drop=var2);
length id 8 var2_context $20;
do until(last.id);
 set have;
by id;
Var2_context = cats(var2_context, var2);
end;
run;
```

or You can also use first. and last. concept as shown below.

```
data want (drop=var2);
length id 8 var2_context $20;
 retain var2_context;
set have;
by id;
if first.id then var2_context = var2;
else Var2_context = cats(var2_context, var2);
if last.id;
run;
```

if your data is not sorted then do a proc sort

```
proc sort data = have;
by id var2;
run;
```

Comment: What does 'length id 8. var2_context $20.;' do?

Comment: var2_context $20. is used to give a minimum length of 20 for var2_context and also  is to indicate it is character variable. if i just  give var2_context, it comes as first variable that is why I am mentioning id a numeric variable as length 8. try without id variable in length statement and check what happens.

Comment: generally length or retain statement will decide the order of variables too

Comment: The LENGTH statement will define the variable. It is always a good practice to define your variables instead of forcing SAS to guess how to define them based on how you first use them. Note that length values do not need decimal points. They are integers. They are also not formats.  `length id 8 var2_context $20;`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other techniques.

The first performs an in DATA step pivot using an array and a DOW loop.  The array is combined using `cat` function.

The second uses wall paper SQL to pivot the data into columns that are concatenated.

```
data have;
attrib
  id   length=8
  Var2 length=$1
;
input ID  Var2 $; datalines;
1   A 
1   B
1   C
2   A
2   B
2   C
2   D
3   A
3   B
4   A 
4   B
4   C
5   A
5   B
5   C
6   A
6   B
6   C
6   D
run;

data want(keep=id combo);
  array across(4) $1;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;

    across(_n_) = Var2;
  end;
  length combo $4;
  combo = cat(of across(*));
run;

proc freq data=want;
  table combo;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select distinct
    have.id,
    A.Var2 || B.Var2 || c.Var2 || D.var2
    as combo
  from 
    have
    left join (select id, Var2 from have where Var2 = 'A') A on have.id = A.id
    left join (select id, Var2 from have where Var2 = 'B') B on have.id = B.id
    left join (select id, Var2 from have where Var2 = 'C') C on have.id = C.id
    left join (select id, Var2 from have where Var2 = 'D') D on have.id = D.id
  ;
```